# Postgres: use function that returns a string in another function

Tags: postgresql, function, return-value

I've a PostgreSQL function that returns a string. I want to use this function into another one but I obtain an error.

These are the sample functions, with `get_some_string` that returns text, and `use_the_string` where I want to call the previous one and store the result in a variable:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_some_string()

RETURNS text AS
$func$
DECLARE

BEGIN

  return 'mystring';

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.use_the_string()

RETURNS boolean AS
$func$
DECLARE

  mytext text;

BEGIN

  mytext := select public.get_some_string();

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

If I run this query I obtain the error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"
LINE 24:   mytext := select public.get_some_string();
```

What I'm doing wrong? How can I use the return value of the first function into the second one?

Comment: mytext := (select public.get_some_string());

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a select:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.use_the_string()

RETURNS boolean AS
$func$
DECLARE

  mytext text;

BEGIN

  mytext := public.get_some_string();

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Answer (score 2):

The second one must be:

```
RETURNS boolean AS
$func$
DECLARE

  mytext text;

BEGIN

  select public.get_some_string() into mytext;

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

or

```
mytext := (select public.get_some_string());
```

or

```
mytext := public.get_some_string();
```

Answer (score 1):

Note to other answers: `select` is implicitly added in plpgsql context. Example:

```
do $$
declare
  v text[];
begin
  v := array_agg(datname) from pg_database;
  raise info 'List of databases: %', v;
end $$;
```

So when you call `mytext := select public.get_some_string();` it is transformed to `select select public.get_some_string();` internally.

Thats why parenthesesis `mytext := (select public.get_some_string());` could be the solution: `select (select public.get_some_string());` is the acceptable statement.